# Get a stacktrace instead of error 0

Tags: debug, error-reporting

I *really* need a stacktrace instead of a stupid "Error 0: Could not connect to MySQL". I've set debugging to on and error reporting to max. Any idea?

**Edit**: Temporary solution: Hacking Joomla core.

**Edit 2**: To be precise, add

```
echo '<pre>'; echo $this->error; echo $this->renderBacktrace(); echo '</pre>'; die;
```

to `render()` in libraries/joomla/document/error.php

**Edit 3**: Since the namespace change, `error.php` has changed location to here: `libraries/src/Document/ErrorDocument.php`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of 3.6.3, the Joomla core templates will give you the stack trace (including any nested Exceptions of the top level object that ultimately gets caught by the error handler) when the site is in debug mode.  Of course, such a feature is also dependent on the template supporting it if it has a custom error.php layout.

See https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/10964 for the relevant changes you would need to make in the error.php file.

Comment: I'm using 3.6.4. Strange. Local installation, no custom templates.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to enable the Debug Mode in Global Settings and then Joomla will display the stack trace on error.